# Angular Custom components not invoking through createElement()

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular

I have created an **angular custom button component**, and when I include the **tagName**(selector) of that component through **createElement()** of JavaScript, I'm not getting any callback to this angular custom component.

I want this **angular custom component** to get **init()** when I include the tag though createElement to the HTMLDom.

How can I do that?

Comment: You can get the "component" inject in constructor ElementRef and use elementRef.nativeElement. Anyway it's not an "angular way" use createElement. Sure you can get your achieve using *ngIf and a variable

Comment: I didn't mean this, actually, I will insert <sample-custom-tag> into Dom HTML which is declared as an angular component already, but it's not detected by this component, It's just left-over as a dummy tag.

Comment: you can not do it, use `<ng-container *ngIf="variable"><sample-custom-tag></sample-custom-tag></ng-container>` and change the "variable" to false of true